# update point after transform

Tags: ios, swift, cgaffinetransform, cgpoint

I'm trying to change a view position using `CGAffineTransform` but the transform statement doesn't affect it.

For example, let's call the view that moves `movingView`:

At the start, `movingView` is at point `CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)`
then I'm moving `movingView` by this code :

```
movingView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 100, y: 300)
```

now if I do : `print(movingView.layer.position)`, I still get

> CGPoint(x: 100, y:100)

instead of

> CGPoint(x: 200, y: 400)

Comment: Are you printing before the animation is completed?

Comment: No, after, in completion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Applying a transform to a view (or layer) doesn't update its center location (or position). It changes how and where the view (or layer) appear on screen but not the values of its `center`, (or `position`), or `bounds` properties.

If you want to know what how the point is affected by a translation, then you can compute a new point by applying the transform to it:

```
let point = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200)
let transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 20, y: 40)
let transformedPoint = point.applying(transform) // x: 120, y: 240
```

Comment: What does it mean to apply a transform to a _point_? For example, suppose we apply a rotation transform? How can this be meaningful unless we get to say what point we are rotating around?

Comment: Never mind, I see: we rotate around the origin, and if you don't like that you have to sandwich the rotation between translations to get the rotation point onto the origin and back again.

Answer (score -1):

Actually What changes is the frame of View if the view is added to a SuperView. 
Check : `movingView.frame.origin`.

The transform of CALayer of UIView has already changed:

CGPoint.init(x: movingView.layer.transform.m41, y: movingView.layer.transform.m42)

So the transform of view is based on transform of CALayer.

Comment: If the view has a transform then its frame shouldn’t be used. See the [documentation for `frame`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622621-frame): “**Warning**
If the `transform` property is not the identity transform, the value of this property is undefined and therefore should be ignored”

Comment: So it’s confusing why view and layer has different transforms. All in all

Comment: Just try to avoid the term of UIView.

Comment: The layout properties of a view and it’s underlying layer are different representations (and different layers of abstraction) of the same information.

Comment: One is 2d one is 3d. UIView is more like CGContext canvas. While CAlayer is from OpenGL like.